# NSPredicate with relationship child entity property

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have this Model situation -

1. `Group` entity is in One on One relationship with `Event` entity called `latestEvent`.
2. `Event` entity has a child entity called 'WeddingEvent' which is one of many child events.
3. `WeddingEvent` is the only one who has a property called `present`
4. I am trying to filter `Group` to not be fetched if the `latestEvent` is of kind 'WeddingEvent'.

Since I can not fetch by className or by entityName I tried :

```
NSPredicate *LatestEventValidity = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latestEvent.present != nil"];
```

AND

```
 NSPredicate *LatestEventValidity = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary * bindings) {
        OOVGroup *group = evaluatedObject;
        return [group.latestEvent respondsToSelector:@selector(setPresent:)];
    }];
```

But they al failed.

Any help here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first predicate does not work because not all Event objects respond to the "present"
selector. The second predicate does not work because you cannot use block-based (or any
Objective-C based) predicates in a Core Data fetch request.

The only solution is probably to add a  (string or integer) "type" attribute to your "Event" entity, so that you can filter with a predicate like `"lastEvent.type != 'Wedding'"`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying why my tries don't work. Your idea is good but I have legacy problems as many users out there already use this app and I wanted to avoid migrations. What I did is to move the present property to the parent Event entity which is supported by light weight migration. Thanks